# How to render Stimulus controller in Twig?

Tags: symfony, twig, stimulusjs

I think this is a simple issue, but I don't understand why it happens:

When I add a stimulus component in Twig this way:

```
{{ stimulus_controller('test')}}
```

it renders the text : data-controller="test"

When I use

```html
<div data-controller='test'></div>
```

the controllers renders perfectly.

Is there a tuning setup to make to activate this twig extension? I didn't find anything this way, and the extension is well recognized by my IDE which place me on the extension declaration.

Answer (score 5):

Just use it like this:

```
<div {{ stimulus_controller('test') }}></div>
```

This will output:

```html
<div data-controller="test"></div>
```

Comment: omg you're right ! thank you, I wasn't awake :( thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

By looking into the `vendor`, you can find the declaration of `stimulus_controller` inside a Twig extension: `Symfony\WebpackEncoreBundle\Twig\StimulusTwigExtension`

The aim of this extension is to render the `data-controller` attribute and, optionnaly, some `data-[controller-identifier]-value` attributes.

It will not render a `div` because your Stimulus controller can be attached to any kind of node in your page (a `span`, the `body`, etc.)